# When button is clicked, create a div, upload an image, and put that image into a div. (Can be done more than once). How do I accomplish this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So far, I got it to create a div and an image. But, the image contains an ID. The first time, it creates a DIV and adds an image to it. But when you click the button (fileupload button) again, it only changes the image in the first div created.

Sidenote: main2 is the DIV i'm trying to add the created div's to.

Main div that will contain the created div's:

```
<div id="main2">
```

Input button:

```
<input type='file' id="imgInp" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

Function:

```
function readURL(input) {

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'main2div')
    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.setAttribute('id', 'newimg')
    var addHere = document.getElementById('main2');
    addHere.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(newImg);

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById('newimg').src =  e.target.result;

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically create a new ID each time.

```
var idseq=0;
function readURL(input) {

    var containerId = 'insertedImage-'+idseq;
    idseq++;

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'main2div')
    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.setAttribute('id', containerId)
    var addHere = document.getElementById('main2');
    addHere.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(newImg);

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById(containerId).src =  e.target.result;

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: why search the dom for an element you just created and already have a reference to?

Comment: @charlietfl I modified the altered the asker's code directly to make the changes more obvious and accessible.